# Marshaller / Marshaler

Tags: orthography

What is the correct spelling of Marshalling/Marshaling? I also have problems with other derived variants of **marshal**:

- marshaller / marshaler
- marshalling / marshaling
- marshalled / marshaled

Google hasn't help much, also different spell checkers have different opinions.

What are the rules here?

Comment: Just to add context: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science) ]

Answer (score 2):

This is just a question of regional convention. British English doubles the 'l' before adding a suffix, and American English doesn't. For instance, *traveller* (Brit) vs. *traveler* (US), or *marvellous* (Brit) vs. *marvelous* (US).

Comment: We double the 'l' if the last syllable is accented, as in *compelling*, *rebelling, extolling.*